# PHP DOMNode insertAfter?

Tags: xml, dom, domdocument, insertafter

I am a bit stuck on how to reorder nodes. I am trying to add two simple "move item up" and "move item down" functions. While insertBefore() does what I want to move a sibling before the preceding one, what is the easiest way to move one node down in the DOM?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Code Example:

```
 try {
        $li->parentNode->insertBefore( $ul, $li->nextSibling);
 } catch(\Exception $e){
        $li->parentNode->appendChild( $ul );
 }
```

Comment: Actually, you can do only: `$li->parentNode->insertBefore( $ul, $li->nextSibling);`   

The try..catch block is unnecessary, because if $li->nextSibling is null, insertBefore() will act just like appendChild().

Comment: What if nextSibling is null (i.e. $li is the last in the series)?

Comment: If `nextSibling` is null, it means `DOMNode::insertBefore` with second parameter omitted. Without second parameter (refnode), newnode is appended to the children. http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php (Tested and works as the #1 comment & manual said)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, stupid me. The easy solution is to just go down in the DOM to the nextSibling of the nextSibling and do the same insertBefore... so this is solved.